# Screen keeps turning off on Ubuntu 17.04 after 30 seconds of inactivity

Tags: suspend, power-management, 17.04, screen

My screen turns off after 30 seconds of inactivity since I installed 17.04.

I've tried so many ways to fix it, including `xset s off` and dpms but it hasn't helped. When I type `xset q` on terminal it gives me this:

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000002
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    on     02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fa9fffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  5/1    threshold:  5
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x20    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

What should I do? Trying change things in settings doesn't work either. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you see System Settings > "Brightness and lock" configuration? Maybe it's settled to turn monitor off after 30s.

Comment: Sadly not, Brightness and lock set to "Never" and energy too. Problem still going =/

Comment: I am not going to post this as an answer, because it's not directly solving the problem. The time you used so far figuring it out, you could possibly have used to re-install the system on your computer. Have you tried that? 
Another thing, have you tried connecting external devices such as mouses and keyboards (if a laptop? it's not specified). Other than that I would have no clue about this issue

Answer (score 8):

I'm sorry that this won't fix *your* problem, but this is the first google result for 'ubuntu screen turning off after 30 seconds of inactivity' and I wanted to share that this problem happened to me on Ubuntu 16.04 after letting my laptop battery fully deplete and force shutdown, and the fix was:

```
xset -dpms
```

This answer is for anyone else that might be helped.  Sorry OP.

Comment: @OP If you try enabling and disabling the dpms? would that solve your Issue?

Comment: This solved the issue for me on Arch as well.